# How to use Java ArrayList for my Snake Game?

Tags: java, arrays

i am still learning in java programming and i still have a long way to go. I tried to coding my first game which is snake game and i encountered some of the problem that i don't really understand.

Here is my code:

**Renderer Class**

```
public class Renderer {

private static Frame frame;
private static Canvas canvas;

private final static int WIDTH = 500;
private final static int HEIGHT = 500;
private final static int tileSize = 25;

private final static int width_game = 510;
private final static int height_game = 510;

private static int ticks = 0;

static Board board = new Board(0,0,tileSize);
static Snake snake;
static int AposX = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
static int AposY = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
static Apple apple = new Apple(AposX, AposY, tileSize);
public static int posX = 7;
public static int posY = 10;
public static int snakeSize = 3;

static Control control;
static int direction = 3;  //0 = up, 1 = right, 2 = down, 3 = left

public static boolean right = true, left = false, up = false, down = false;

public static ArrayList <Snake> snakeList = new ArrayList<Snake>();

public static void init(){
    frame = new Frame();
    canvas = new Canvas();

    //Add user control
    control = new Control(direction);
    canvas.addKeyListener(control);
    canvas.setFocusable(true);

    canvas.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setTitle("Snake Game");
    frame.setResizable(false);      
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            Main.quit();
        }
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);

    startRendering();
}

public static void startRendering(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(){                   
        public void run(){          
            while(true){
                draw();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

public static void draw(){
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = canvas.getGraphicsConfiguration();
    VolatileImage vImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    while(true){
        ticks++;

        if(vImage.validate(gc) == VolatileImage.IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE){
            vImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        }

        Graphics g = vImage.getGraphics();

        //Clear Frame
        g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //To create Snake in the start inside the array             
        int index = 0;
        while(snakeList.size() != snakeSize){
            snake = new Snake(posX, posY, tileSize);
            snakeList.add(snake);
        }

        //Frame to update the snake to move
        if(ticks > 100){
            direction = control.getDirection();

            if(direction == 1)posX++;
            if(direction == 3)posX--;
            if(direction == 2)posY++;
            if(direction == 0)posY--;

            snake = new Snake(posX, posY, tileSize);
            snakeList.add(snake);   

            if(snakeList.size() > snakeSize){
                snakeList.remove(0);
            }
            ticks = 0;

            //If the snake out of the area, it will go back to another side
            if(posX > 20){posX = -1;}
            if(posX < -1){posX = 20;}
            if(posY > 20){posY = -1;}
            if(posY < -1){posY = 20;}

            if(snakeList.get(0).getSnakePosX() == apple.getApplePosX() && snakeList.get(0).getSnakePosY() == apple.getApplePosY()){
                apple.update();
                snakeSize++;
            }
        }

        //Rendering the snake
        for(int x = 0; x < snakeList.size(); x++){
            snakeList.get(x).render(g);
        }

        //Rendering the apple
        apple.render(g);

        //Rendering the board grid
        board.render(g);

        g = canvas.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(vImage, 0, 0, width_game, height_game, null);

        g.dispose();
    }
}
}
```

**Snake**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Snake {
public int posX;
public int posY;
public int tileSize;
final static public int height = 500;
final static public int width = 500;
public int direction = 1; //0 = up, 1 = right, 2 = down, 3 = left

public Snake(int posX, int posY, int tileSize){
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(posX*tileSize, posY*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
}

public void update(){

}

public int getSnakePosX(){return posX;}
public int getSnakePosY(){return posY;}
}
```

Okay the problem is that snake will make a contact with the apple at the end of the tail instead of the head. But in the code

```
if(snakeList.get(0).getSnakePosX() == apple.getApplePosX() && snakeList.get(0).getSnakePosY() == apple.getApplePosY()){
            apple.update();
            snakeSize++;
        }
```

I clearly define the first index which is 0 which is the first of the snake body part has been made which is the head. I can't find out the problem here. The head of the array is at [2].

I hope that this is really help and i get the solution soon,
Thank you.

Here is the area that i think might be the problem:

```
            while(snakeList.size() != snakeSize){
            snake = new Snake(posX, posY, tileSize);
            snakeList.add(snake);
        }
```

The code above is for the creation of the first 3 body part.

```
if(snakeList.get(0).getSnakePosX() == apple.getApplePosX() && snakeList.get(0).getSnakePosY() == apple.getApplePosY()){
                apple.update();
                snakeSize++;
            }
```

This one here is so that if there is a collision, the size of the snake will be increased.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this question isn't well structured for this forum. You will need to remove all the code that has nothing to do with your problem and try to come up with a small example that demonstrates where you are stuck. If you find that hard to do then I suggest you start with a debugger to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Very poorly asked, could you elaborate more please?

Comment: I gave the whole code because i think it would be better if you can see it by yourself. So here is the problem. There is 3 body part of the snake for starter. The head of the snake which is the first body should the the one to hit the apple and gain one more body part. Instead the last body part which is the tail the the one that does that. So basically the problem class is in the render under the snake and apple coding.

Comment: Put yourself in our position. Somebody asks a question and throws a thousand lines of unfamiliar code at you. How would you go about answering that question? Please read this page about how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The process will probably help you solve it on your own, but in case it doesn't, you'll be able to ask a much more direct question about code that fits in maybe 10-20 lines, which is much easier for people to help you with.

Comment: Okat, my bad because i'm still new with this and the website. I edited the last part where i think might be the problem